# Spring Boot version versus Spring Framework version?

Tags: spring-boot

Given that you know the Spring Boot version used by an application, how do you find the underlying Spring (Framework) version?

Suppose you're the user of a Spring Boot application. The application log shows the Spring Boot version.

The application uses some Spring features that depend on the underlying Spring version. For example, Spring Expression Language (SpEL). To view the relevant version-specific docs for SpEL, you need to know the Spring version. Here's the URL for the SpEL docs for Spring 5.3.18:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.18/reference/html/core.html#expressions

How does the user of a Spring Boot application know which version of the Spring (Framework) docs to look at?

One person has told me that, as far as they know, "SpEL is stable", and so, the specific Spring version is not that significant. Still, the fact remains: *the SpEL docs are Spring-version-specific*. I'd like to view the docs that match the Spring version of the app. But perhaps I should have picked a different example Spring feature.

### Am I missing something?

Examples of content that occurs to me might exist, and that I've looked for, but not found:

- In the Spring Boot docs, is there a formatted HTML table that maps *Spring Boot* versions to *Spring Framework* versions?
- In the docs for each version of Spring Boot, is there a link to the docs for the corresponding version of Spring? That is, do the [Spring Boot 2.6.6 docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.6/reference/htmlsingle/) contain a link to the Spring 5.3.18 docs?

Comment: Re: "In the docs for each version of Spring Boot, is there a link to the docs for the corresponding version of Spring?" Yes. Yes, there is. See my grovelling [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75640385/1334619).

Answer (score 8):

Here is a quick way to find which version of spring-core is used.

Google “spring-boot-starter-test”.

Click on the first link that comes back - [spring-boot-starter-test on mvnrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test)

Click in the version of interest, eg 2.6.6

Find the spring-core dependency: 5.3.18

Comment: I like this, thank you! Yes, I see the 5.3.18 dependency listed there. I guess the only thing giving me pause for thought is the "or above" in the "5.3.18" or above" requirement cited in the Spring Boot 2.6.6 docs. What I think this means: while "out of the box" Spring Boot 2.6.6 uses Spring 5.3.18, an application could choose to use a later version of Spring. And, as far as I can tell, the application user won't know that unless the application developer deliberately reports the Spring version in the application log.

Answer (score 2):

Spring-Boot     vs    Spring-Framework

- 3.1.2        ->         6.0.11               [Spring-Boot-3.1-Release-Notes](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test)
- 2.7.14       ->         5.3.29               [Spring-Boot-3.0-Release-Notes](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test)
- 2.6.15       ->         5.3.27               [Spring-Boot-2.7-Release-Notes](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test)
- 2.5.15       ->         5.3.27               [Spring-Boot-2.6-Release-Notes](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test)
- 2.4.13       ->         5.3.13               [Spring-Boot-2.4-Release-Notes](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test)
- 2.3.12.RELEASE       ->         5.2.15.RELEASE
- 2.3.6.RELEASE        ->         5.2.11.RELEASE

[cf: mvnrepository.com](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test)
[cf: release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki#release-notes)
[cf: Spring-Boot-Older-Release-Notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-Older-Release-Notes)

JDK Version Range
Spring Framework 6.2.x: JDK 17-25 (expected)
Spring Framework 6.1.x: JDK 17-23
Spring Framework 6.0.x: JDK 17-21
Spring Framework 5.3.x: JDK 8-21 (as of 5.3.26)

[cf: github.com/spring-projects](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Spring-Framework-Versions)

Answer (score 1):

Find the reference to Spring Framework in the `build.gradle` file in the source for that Spring Boot version in GitHub.

For example, from the [`build.gradle` for Spring Boot 2.6.6](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.6.6/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/build.gradle#L1702):

```
library("Spring Framework", "5.3.18")
```

But, is this the *best* answer?

The most *user-friendly* way for an application user, who might not typically look at `build.gradle` files, to "map" Spring Boot version 2.6.6 to Spring Framework version 5.3.18, so they can find the relevant Spring Framework docs?

Answer (score 0):

The Spring Boot docs *already* link to the correct Spring version docs.

For example, in the [Spring Boot 2.6.6 docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.6/reference/htmlsingle/#features.developing-auto-configuration.condition-annotations.spel-conditions):

> #### SpEL Expression Conditions
>
> The @ConditionalOnExpression annotation lets configuration be included based on the result of a [SpEL expression](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.18/reference/html/core.html#expressions).

The text "SpEL expression" links to the corresponding Spring 5.3.18 docs.

Also from the [Spring Boot 2.6.6 docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.6/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started.system-requirements):

> ### 4.2. System Requirements
>
> Spring Boot 2.6.6 requires Java 8 and is compatible up to and including Java 17. [Spring Framework 5.3.18](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.18/reference/html/) or above is also required.

I'm out of excuses. It's right there under "Getting Started", in plain sight; not "hidden" behind a link URL.

I'm embarrassed to admit that I just hadn't noticed this before. Writing this question reinforced the feeling that I was missing something. I was. The writers of those docs might justifiably consider that what caused *me* to miss this information *cannot be fixed*.  Perhaps I just should delete this entire question. I'm open to that. Then again, perhaps, by leaving this question, I might save someone else the same embarrassment. Bottom line: RTFM!

And yet: "Spring Framework 5.3.18 *or above*". That seems to allow for the possibility that "Spring Boot 2.6.6 *indicates* Spring Framework 5.3.18" is simplistic, potentially misleading; that an application that cites Spring Boot 2.6.6 in its log might be using a version of Spring Framework *later* than 5.3.18. How would the *application user* know?